# To find the video file orientation

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm playing a video from the sdcard and it's working fine. But my requirement is that I need to play a video based on its orientation (if the video orientation is landscape, then I need to play a video in landscape mode). I searched this on many forums but I could not get any solution. So, someone please help me out from this.

Thanks in advance
MMRPs

Comment: you are duplicating your own questions on SO. Please delete one of the question and add any additional comments to the other